# Out of Memory Threading - Perf Test Tool

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool, out-of-memory

I'm creating a tool to load test (sends http: GETs) and it runs fine but eventually dies because of an out of memory error.

**ASK:** How can I reset the threads so this loop can continually run and not err?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 200;

       while (true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                new Thread(LoadTest).Start(); //<-- EXCEPTION!.eventually errs out of memory
            }
            Thread.Sleep(2);
        }
    }

    static void LoadTest()
    {
        string url = "http://myserv.com/api/dev/getstuff?whatstuff=thisstuff";

        // Sends http get from above url ... and displays the repose in the console....
    }
```

Comment: A sane implementation of you infrastructure would mean this might not stress test the correct component. You are doing an HTTP GET, which is meant to be a Pure Function. This means that any caching is allowed to assume the same result each time. You could in theory be only making a SINGLE HTTP request with 1000 threads.

Comment: @Aron: How can I prevent the cacheing from happening? That is why I was making calls to all those threads separately so as not to make a single GET with those 1000 threads. In my GET request I include a &_=<Ticks> (i.e. http://...getstuff?whatstuff=thisstuff&_=23424).

Comment: @Aron: Cool, thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are instantiating Threads left right and centre. This is likely you problem. You want to replace the

```
new Thread(LoadTest).Start();
```

with

```
Task.Run(LoadTest);
```

This will run your LoadTest on a Thread in the ThreadPool, instead of using resources to create a new Thread each time. HOWEVER. This will then expose a different issue.

Threads on the ThreadPool are a limited resource and you want to return Threads to the ThreadPool as soon as possible. I assume you are using the synchronous download methods as opposed to the APM methods. This means that whilst the request is being sent out to the server, the thread spawning the request is sleeping as opposed to going off to do some other work.

Either use (assuming .net 4.5)

```
var client = new WebClient();
var response = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
Console.WriteLine(response);
```

Or use a callback (if not .net 4.5)

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.OnDownloadStringCompleted(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
client.BeginDownloadString(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) and use QueueUserWorkItem instead of creating thousands of threads. Threads are expensive objects and it is no surprise you are running out of memory and besides you won't be able to have any performance (in your test tool) with so many threads.

Answer (score 1):

You code snippet creates lots of threads and no wonder it eventually runs out of memory. It would be better to use a Thread Pool here.
You code would look like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 200;
        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(500, 300);
        while (true)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(LoadTest);
        }
    }

    static void LoadTest(object state)
    {
        string url = "http://myserv.com/api/dev/getstuff?whatstuff=thisstuff";
        // Sends http get from above url ... and displays the repose in the console....
    }
```

Comment: You don't actually need 500 threads to run 200 http connections, if you use async code. In fact trying to run 200 threads is going to kill you computer most likely.

Comment: Totally agree with you. I put it there just for configuration example. The advice is, be logical and decide for yourself :). Besides, it's just maximum number of threads. The pool does not create 500 threads right away.